# How can I find out the click event for Bootstrap Pills?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap pills in my code, but now I want to perform another action when a pill is clicked. But none of the event handlers are able to capture the click event,any help appreciated. Thanks

I've added click events on the a tag, and the parents as well, I have also added a click event used for bootstrap tabs, but that didnt work as well

```
   <ul id="accountPills" class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
         <a id="OrderHistory" class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Order History</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
         <a id="AccountInformation" class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Account Information</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
         <a id="Addresses" class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Addresses</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: Could you please put your JQuery/Javascript code as well? jsfiddle would work as well.

Comment: Please share jQuery code of click event.

Comment: @DarshanThakkar HI, this is my code 

```
  $('a[data-toggle="pill"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    var target = $(e.target).attr("href");
  alert(target)
});
```

Comment: Just tested your code, works. If you experience troubles, i guess it is not related to the way you define event listeners

Answer (score 3):

`Pills` are an implementation of the `nav` functionality which provides an events `API`:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#events

```
$('a[data-toggle="pill"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  e.target // newly activated tab
  e.relatedTarget // previous active tab
})
```